# Error While deploying JRuby app using apache tomcat

Tags: ruby, tomcat, jruby

I have deployed WAR file in apache tomcat . WAR file is made in JRuby using Ruby 2.2.3 in ubuntu.

But when I ran the tomcat, I am getting following error. How can I resolve this error? 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the given error, you have installed Ruby 1.9.3 on your system but you have mentioned ruby 2.2.3 in the Gemfile.

So Install the required ruby version. If you are using RVM try following command

```
rvm install 2.2.3
```